# Stack Overflow Error when using string length to a string pointer

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, string-length

Currently creating a C program to reverse a name with the use of pointers and a function. I get a stack overflow error when attempting to use strlen() on char *name. I have not fully created the function yet as I'm currently hitting this problem with strlen().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void format_name();

int main(void)
{
    char str[256+1];
    char *name = &str[0];


    printf("Enter the first and last name: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str);
    printf("formatting name\n");
    format_name (*name);

    printf("Formatted name: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}



void format_name (char *name)
{
    int spacepos = 0;


    printf("Finding string length");
    int length = strlen(name);
    printf("Size of string = %d", length);

    for(p = 0; p <= length - 1; p++)
        {
            printf("Checking position %d", p);

            if(name[p] == ' ' && spacepos == 0)
                {
                    spacepos = p;
                    printf("first space found at pos %d", p);
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: `format_name (*name);`, `*name` is a `char`; argument types mismatch

Comment: Fix the function prototype at the top. It should be `void format_name(char *);`. Then you would have gotten a warning about the type mismatch in the call.

Comment: Also `strlen` returns `size_t`, not `int`; use `%zu` instead of `%d`

Comment: `format_name (*name);` should be `format_name (name);`

Comment: Also use `scanf("%256[^\n]s", str);` to prevent buffer overruns

Comment: And while your code isn't wrong, `char *name = &str[0];` is usually written as just `char *name = str;`. I'm not sure why you think you need a new variable for this, though.